3 220 circuits for 1 outdoor A/C condenser?
I just purchased a rental property with forced hot air a/c and heat. The 200 amp service box is brand new and has 3 double 20 amp breakers all in a row all labeled a/c. Does the condenser require 3 separate 220v circuits?

Probably not.  Someone might have been lazy with labelling and two should be heat instead of AC.  You will need the check the labels on the unit/s and see what they require.  Size of property is important to know also.  A 10 room mansion might need three while a two bedroom will not.

What you probably have is one set of breakers for the condenser, one set for a Heat strip and one set for the air handler fan.

Can you post photos of the nameplates on the indoor and outdoor units please?
